# Recurrence interval for minutes reminder in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a program that triggers a reminder after 30 minutes.  I would like to change it so that the reminder will be triggered every 30 minutes without any user interaction.  I don't want them to have to press a button to trigger the timer, like they currently have to.  Here is what I have so far:

```
            Reminder r = new Reminder("REMINDER..");
            r.Title = "REMINDER..";
            r.Content = "YOU CAN SMOKE AT THIS TIME";
            r.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            r.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            ScheduledActionService.Add(r);
```

Comment: Lok background agent et azure push notification.

Comment: Would you be more interested in using a Toast Notification or a Live Tile? Not sure if you can trigger a reminder with a background task... but a background task is what you want.